# problems connecting with bitcoin RPC

Tags: php, api, rpc, bitcoin

I was setting up a faucet to give away some btc at nobanchan.com/faucet

The problem I am having is 
 Fatal error: Uncaught BitcoinClientException: [0]: Connect error: Connection refused (111) thrown in on line 0

I have the RPC username/password/port in bitcoin.conf exactly the same as I do on config.php for the faucet.

I have forwarded the port from my WAN to my private IP in my router.

I have reopened bitcoin a few times. Also, I have set rpcallowip= my local IP, and my websites IP.

What else should I check?!

Comment: connection refused means a network error. connecting the wrong server or wrong port on the server, or a firewall is actively denying the connection. you haven't even connected to the stage where the username/password would come into play. a u/p error would get reported as "permission denied".

Comment: In this case "Connection refused" does not mean a network error. A network error would be "failed to open stream: HTTP request failed" (which I got when trying to connect to the port of the main deamon).
"failed to open stream: Connection refused" means you have connected to the right port but the server does not accept your request. See https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Enabling_SSL_on_original_client_daemon

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with two servers trying to let them communicate.

It seems like you have to set up "JSON-RPC Over SSL" as described here if you don't run client and server on the same machine (e.g. if you do not use "localhost"):

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Enabling_SSL_on_original_client_daemon

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @lagopixel here, I don't think this is a network error.

First, **if you want to use RPC commands with the bitcoin core you should add the "server" option** (-server on command line or server=1 in bitcoin.conf).

Then, I'm pretty sure this has nothing to do with SSL conections but here are the options related to SSL for the bitcoin core (just in case):

- rpcssl: Use OpenSSL (https) for JSON-RPC connections
- rpcsslcertificatechainfile=file.cert: Server certificate file (default: server.cert)
- rpcsslprivatekeyfile=file.pem: Server private key (default:server.pem)
- rpcsslciphers=ciphers: Acceptable ciphers (default: TLSv1.2+HIGH:TLSv1+HIGH:!SSLv2:!aNULL:!eNULL:!3DES:@STRENGTH)

Moreover, note that using JSON-RPC over SSL is strongly discouraged.